# Ругается на класс. Yii2: Модели

Tags: php, yii2

Не понимаю, почему ошибка?

```
syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting ',' or ';'

in C:\xampp\htdocs\controllers\EmployeeController.php


<?php 
namespace app\controllers;

use yii\web\Controller;
use app\models\Employee

class EmployeeController extends Controller
{

    public function actionIndex()
    {




    }
}
```

/////////////////////////////////

```
<?php 

namespace app\models;
use yii\base\Model;

class Employee extends Model{
    public $firstName;
    public $lastName;
    public $middleName;
    public $salary;
}
```

Comment: `;` тут - `use app\models\Employee` ?

Comment: Спасибо, невнимательность меня всегда подводит